Generating a jaxrs-jersey server using the Jakarta namespace?
I am currently trying to update Apache IoTDB from the javax to the jakarta namespace.
Here we have one module, that we use to generate the rest server for the DB using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin and the jaxrs-jersey generator.
So I added the config option useJakartaEe=true to the maven config and it corretly now references the jakarta packages.
Unfortunately the Providers all extend from JacksonJaxbJsonProvider and the only version of this which I could find internally references javax packages.
How can I completely switch my code generation to only use jakarta packages?

Perhaps you can provide the branch with Apache IoTDB？
I tried to change useJakartaEe=true, but I didn't see any more code useful for Javax. How did you discover the problem.
i found this https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers?tab=readme-ov-file#using-jakarta
Using Jakarta
Starting with Jackson 2.13, there is a fully separate set of providers for "Jakarta-RS", see: jackson-jakarta-rs-providers. They would be instead included with:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>


So I've staged my changes in this PR: https://github.com/apache/iotdb/pull/12520
I also already had added the jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider artifact, but that didn't seem to do the trick as the package name is in is different and the generated types are referring to JacksonJaxbJsonProvider and not JacksonJsonProvider.

Digging a bit more through my problem, I seem to have found a solution: I added
                            <library>jersey3</library>

To the configuration and with that I seem to be able to successfully generate the jackarta server.
